# How do I stub a method in an object that is loaded in my class/method under test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, sinon, sinon-chai

Our `MEANJS` application has a class (E.g., `CompanyService`) that loads an object (E.g., `CompanyRepo`) of another class and calls a method on it.  I am trying to write unit tests for the `CompanyService` class and would need to stub a method in the `CompanyRepo` method to simulate a promise rejection. However, despite the stub, the `CompanyService` method call seems to call the actual `CompanyRepo` method call.

The code flow is as below,

companyService method

```
function isDomainExists(domain) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        companyRepo.getCompanyByDomain(domain)
                .then(function (company) {
                    return resolve(company);
                }, function(rejected) {
                    return reject("Error");
                })
    } });
```

Unit test method

```
var stub = sinon.stub(companyRepo,"getCompanyByDomain").rejects("error"); it('Should return company not registered if there is a DB error', function() {
    return companyService.isDomainExists("test company").should.eventually.be.rejected(); }); stub.restore();
```

Output

> Company service 
>          isDomainExists method
>            Should return company not registered if there is a DB error:
>        AssertionError: expected promise to be rejected but it was fulfilled with { Object ($__, isNew, ...) }

I think I can understand what is happening here. The companyService class has a require statement that loads the companyRepo class which gets executed even before the stubbing happens. Is there any method by which I can avoid this from happening? What is the recommended best practice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work properly with should, but did get this to work, see if it helps:

companyService:

```
var companyRepo = require('./companyRepo');

function isDomainExists(domain) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        companyRepo.getCompanyByDomain(domain)
            .then(function (company) {
                console.log('----in main resolve')
                return resolve(company);
            }, function (rejected) {
                console.log('----in error catch')
                // return reject(new Error('Errorx'));
                return reject('Error');
            });
    });
};

exports.isDomainExists = isDomainExists;
```

companyRepo

```
exports.getCompanyByDomain = () => { 
    console.log('-----in real getCompanyByDomain');

    return Promise.resolve('resolve from real function');
}
```

Test

```
it('Should return company not registered if there is a DB error', async function () {
    var stub = sinon.stub(companyRepo, "getCompanyByDomain").rejects("fake_error");

    await expect(companyService.isDomainExists("test company")).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith('Error');

    stub.restore();
});
```

It is rejecting with Error (and not fake_error) because your reject function sends 'Error' regardless.

Should sometimes acts funny, no idea why, also, try moving stub / resotre inside the test (or in beforeEach, afterEach).

There was also a small typo in companyRepo definition.

If nothing else works (i've seen this in some cases), try rewire to stub instead:

```
var rewire = require('rewire')
//notice not using require here
var companyService = rewire('./companyService');

it('should stub', async () => {
    let fake = {
        getCompanyByDomain: () => {
            console.log('------rewired stub')
            return Promise.reject('rewired_error');
        }
    }

    companyService.__set__('companyRepo', fake);

    await expect(companyService.isDomainExists("test company")).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith('Error');
    //reset
    companyService = rewire('./companyService');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions @Mankind1023. I'll try these out next week and see if they work.